# Implementing Modified HMAC

Tags: c#, cryptography, hmac

So I am trying to implement my small, modified version of the [HMAC function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Design_principles) for academic purposes. Here is the algorithm as provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Design_principles):

```
function hmac (key, message)
    if (length(key) > blocksize) then
        key = hash(key) // keys longer than blocksize are shortened
    end if
    if (length(key) < blocksize) then
        // keys shorter than blocksize are zero-padded (where ∥ is concatenation)
        key = key ∥ [0x00 * (blocksize - length(key))] // Where * is repetition.
    end if

    o_key_pad = [0x5c * blocksize] ⊕ key // Where blocksize is that of the underlying hash function
    i_key_pad = [0x36 * blocksize] ⊕ key // Where ⊕ is exclusive or (XOR)

    return hash(o_key_pad ∥ hash(i_key_pad ∥ message)) // Where ∥ is concatenation
end function
```

Here is the code I wrote (obviously this gives me inappropriate result, I checked with a given solution). **The block size is 512 bits.**

I think I have already identified one key reason why my code fails, I am not implementing the padding logic for the key, **because I am asked to put leading zeros and not trailing zeroes like the original algorithm**.

**And I don't really know if using leading zeroes padding will make any difference for the mathematics, or how to use it**

Secondly, I am not sure if I am doing the byte math correctly.

Here is my code:

```
private static string HMAC(string message)
{
    //Every charecter corresponds to 4bits.
    long hex_key = 0x0a7cb27e52;

    //padding for an 64 Bit Key. 2 Chars  = 1 Byte. Leading zeros I need (512-(10*4))/4 = 118
    string asc_key = "0a7cb27e52";
    //Did Not KnowWhere To Use
    asc_key = asc_key.PadLeft(128, '0');

    byte[] keyInBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(asc_key);
    var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(keyInBytes);
    hexString = hexString.Replace("-", "");

    //Wikipedia Style naming

    long o_key_pad = (0x5c * 0x40) ^ hex_key;
    long i_key_pad = (0x36 * 0x40) ^ hex_key;
    return GetMD5Hash(o_key_pad.ToString() + GetMD5Hash(i_key_pad.ToString() + message));
}


public static String GetMD5Hash(String TextToHash)
{
    //Check wether data was passed
    if ((TextToHash == null) || (TextToHash.Length == 0))
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    //Calculate MD5 hash. This requires that the string is splitted into a byte[].
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] textToHash = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(TextToHash);
    byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(textToHash);

    //Convert result back to string.
    return System.BitConverter.ToString(result);
}
```

Where have I done wrong?

Comment: Yes, you've forgot adhere to the definition of `*` when implementing `i_pad` and `o_pad`. Also, `long` is not a useful type for the paddings.

Comment: @ArtjomB. What is the definition of `*` and which datatype to use for padding?

Comment: There is a comment on the 7th line which reads "// Where * is repetition.". You've used the symbol literally as multiplication. Anyway, since a long cannot hold 512 bits of data, you need some other data type such as a byte array and iterate over it to XOR in the corresponding key bytes.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks, I totally missed it. Can you explain what `[0x5c * blocksize]` would mean programmatically?

Comment: A suggestion.  Start by writing a standard HMAC, and get it working correctly.  There are plenty of test vectors out there to let you check your work.  When, and only when, you have the standard version working correctly should you move on the build the non-standard version, using as many parts as you can from your working standard version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not implementing the padding logic for the key, because I am
>   asked to put leading zeros and not trailing zeroes like the original
>   algorithm.
>
> And I don't really know if using leading zeroes padding will make any
>   difference for the mathematics, or how to use it

It doesn't change anything in the math, but the result will be different.

> Secondly, I am not sure if I am doing the byte math correctly.

You're not doing it correctly. There are lots of problems with your code:

- Key might have any length and it's common to have a key longer than 64 bits, which would exceed the size of `long`.
- `o_key_pad` and `i_key_pad` are not repeated to fill up the block size.
- `HMAC` and `GetMD5Hash` take and deliver `string` data. Cryptographic operations should be executed on binary data, but not on strings.

Code:

```
private static int BlockSize = 64;

public static byte[] HMAC(byte[] message)
{
    byte[] key = {0x0a, 0x7c, 0xb2, 0x7e, 0x52};
    if (key.Length > BlockSize) {
        key = GetMD5Hash(key);
    }
    byte[] paddedKey = new byte[BlockSize];
    key.CopyTo(paddedKey, BlockSize-key.Length);

    byte[] o_key_pad = new byte[BlockSize];
    byte[] i_key_pad = new byte[BlockSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < BlockSize; i++) {
        o_key_pad[i] = (byte)(0x5c ^ paddedKey[i]);
        i_key_pad[i] = (byte)(0x36 ^ paddedKey[i]);
    }

    byte[] inner_hash = GetMD5Hash(concat(i_key_pad, message));
    return GetMD5Hash(concat(o_key_pad, inner_hash));
}

private static byte[] concat(byte[] a1, byte[] a2) {
    byte[] res = new byte[a1.Length + a2.Length];
    a1.CopyTo(res, 0);
    a2.CopyTo(res, a1.Length);
    return res;
}

private static byte[] GetMD5Hash(byte[] ToHash)
{
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    return md5.ComputeHash(ToHash);
}
```

You can write a wrapper around `HMAC` to take and deliver `string`.